# Does OData v4 not support Nullable<DateTime>?

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

> The type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   of property 'DataAlteracaoDate' in the 'WebAPIOData.Models.Categoria'
>   type is not a supported type. Parameter name: navigationProperty

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentException: The type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' of property 'DataAlteracaoDate' in
>   the 'WebAPIOData.Models.Categoria' type is not a supported type.
>   Parameter name: navigationProperty]
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.EntityTypeConfiguration.AddNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo
>   navigationProperty, EdmMultiplicity multiplicity, Boolean
>   containsTarget) +1054
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.EntityTypeConfiguration.AddNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo
>   navigationProperty, EdmMultiplicity multiplicity) +47
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapEntityType(EntityTypeConfiguration
>   entity) +447
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapType(StructuralTypeConfiguration
>   edmType) +120
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapTypes() +104
>   System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
>   +195    WebAPIOData.WebApiConfig.GetModel() in c:\Projetos\HND022Git\SmartSales\Implementacao\Codigo\Web\SmartSales\WebAPIOData\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:65
>   WebAPIOData.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) in
>   c:\Projetos\HND022Git\SmartSales\Implementacao\Codigo\Web\SmartSales\WebAPIOData\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:25
>   WebAPIOData.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Projetos\HND022Git\SmartSales\Implementacao\Codigo\Web\SmartSales\WebAPIOData\Global.asax.cs:21
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The type
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' of property
>   'DataAlteracaoDate' in the 'WebAPIOData.Models.Categoria' type is not
>   a supported type. Parameter name: navigationProperty]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9936761
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The type
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' of property
>   'DataAlteracaoDate' in the 'WebAPIOData.Models.Categoria' type is not
>   a supported type. Parameter name: navigationProperty]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

My class has a property "*DataAlteracaoDate*" of type ***`Nullable<DateTime>`***

I'm setting the entity on ODataModelBuilder on this way:

```
builder.EntitySet<Categoria>("Categorias").EntityType.HasKey(t => t.IdCategoria);
```

I'm using the lasted version for Prerelease Microsoft.AspNet.OData.5.2.0-rc-140512 in my app.

Does anybody has any suggestion?

Comment: Vote for them to bring back support for DateTime type https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2072 and http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/6242255-odata-v4-service-should-support-datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime is no longer supported in OData v4. What it supports is DateTimeOffset, either nullable or not.

Comment: If I use OData v4 in my app will I have to change all DateTime types for DateTimeOffSet, including on my database?

Comment: I don't think you have to change Datetime in database to DatetimeOffset. In the controller actions, you have to change to data to DateTime before saving it to database and change it back to DateTimeOffset after retrieving it from database.

Comment: Is there a generic way to do this?

Comment: I don't know. All the options as far as I know is here:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829422/handling-dates-with-odata-v4-ef6-and-web-api-v2-2/25076353#25076353>.