# Handling Dates with OData v4, EF6 and Web API v2.2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm in the midst of upgrading from v1-3 to v4, but I've run into a few problems.

My understanding is that DateTime is unsupported, and I have to always use DateTimeOffset. Fine.

But before I was storing Sql `date` data type in the DateTime, now it seems I get this error:

```
Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 'CreatedDate' in type 'MyEntity' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.date[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]'
```

What is the work around for this? I need to be able to store specifically just dates in the database (time and locality is not important). Would be great if I could get the Edm.Date aswell as a returned data type, but I didn't have that before.

Thanks.

Edit: Example classes

Before:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime LoggedDate { get; set; }
}
```

After:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTimeOffset LoggedDate { get; set; }
}
```

This isn't valid in EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone coming to this in the future, the OData v4 team have fixed this issue.

```
[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

This will now auto-resolve to Edm.Date.

If you are like me and are doing `date` type by convention, you have to manually declare the properties as dates lest they be auto-resolved as DateTimeOffset. OData currently does not allow you to add your own conventions.

```
customer.Property(c => c.Birthday).AsDate();
```

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#12-01-DateAndTimeOfDayWithEF

Comment: You can use conventions to apply this across your entire model, as long as EVERY DateTime property should be interpreted as a Date. You can write your convention such that Date is used when a DateType or Column with Type attribute has not been defined which will allow conventions and attribute notation to coexist.

Answer (score 12):

One option is to define a new property in the entity. Say Title is mapped to EF:

```
public partial class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

then add a new property of DateTimeOffset:

```
public partial class Title
{
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTimeOffset? EdmCreatedOn
    {
        // Assume the CreateOn property stores UTC time.
        get
        {
            return CreatedOn.HasValue ? new DateTimeOffset(CreatedOn.Value, TimeSpan.FromHours(0)) : (DateTimeOffset?)null;
        }
        set
        {
            CreatedOn = value.HasValue ? value.Value.UtcDateTime : (DateTime?)null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the code for generate OData Model looks like:

```
    public static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        EntityTypeConfiguration<Title> titleType= builder.EntityType<Title>();
        titleType.Ignore(t => t.CreatedOn);
        titleType.Property(t => t.EdmCreatedOn).Name = "CreatedOn";

        builder.EntitySet<Title>("Titles");

        builder.Namespace = typeof(Title).Namespace;

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

The controller looks like:

```
public class TitlesController : ODataController
{
    CustomerManagementSystemEntities entities = new CustomerManagementSystemEntities();

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10, MaxExpansionDepth = 5)]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        IQueryable<Title> titles = entities.Titles;
        return Ok(titles);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Title title)
    {
        entities.Titles.Add(title);
        return Created(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is the correct one also because it doesn't change the Metadata generated, please mark this solution as the correct one

Comment: Actually you should get a runtime error with this code. The runtime will give error for any entity property of Nullable<System.DateTime> or DateTime?. Does not matter if you ignore the property at ODataConventionModelBuilder configuration level. At least that is what I get.

Comment: The code listed does work until you try to do a $select.

Comment: Has anyone cracked this code yet?  Not sure why it's marked as the answer if you can't do a $select on it without an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below to define your `DateTimeAndDateTimeOffsetWrapper` to do the translation between two types.

http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-sql-spatial-data-with-wcf-odata-spatial/

Define two properties on your model, one is `DateTime` which only exists in the Edm model, the other is `DateTimeOffset` which only exists in the DB.

---

If the solution above doesn't meet your request, you have to change the data to `DateTime` **before saving it to database** and change it back to `DateTimeOffset` after retrieving it from database in the controller actions.

You can define two almost-same classes to achieve this. The only difference is that one has `DateTime` property and the other has `DateTimeOffset` property.

The former one is used for EF and mapping into DB.

The latter one is used for defining OData Edm model and presenting to the users.

As I said above, you have to do the translation between these two classes before saving the data and after retrieving the data.

Comment: It sounds like the second option may be what I need, but wouldn't I lose all $expand functionality since it no longer was a database entity?

Comment: Also I've added classes to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You can retrive the data from DB as OldTicket, and then translate the data to NewTicket. After this is done, you can apply the $expand and other query options. However this part will be done in memory with linq-to-objects, rather than linq-to-entities in old way. Anyway it is a work around.

Comment: Not very happy with how hacky it is. Hopefully MS will produce a functioning library instead of the mess it is right now. I will stick with OData v3 until then. I will award you the bounty if no one else gives a work around thats easier.

Comment: Keep an eye on the status of codeplex issue about DateTime:) https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2072 Now the spatial types have same problem because EF can't map these Edm spatial types. Spatial types are tracked by https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1010

Comment: Thanks I've been annoyed by the spatial types aswell. Will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the AppendDatetimeOffset method to add automatically the methods 
using the microsoft T4 engine (i.e. updating the template file *.tt). So that when regenerating the code, you don't have to append classes again. Hope this Helps :)

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            (_ef.IsKey(edmProperty) ? "[Key]" : "") +
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}  {5}",           
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
            AppendDateTimeOffset(edmProperty));
    }

    public string AppendDateTimeOffset(EdmProperty edmProperty){

     if(!_typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage).Contains("DateTime")) return " ";
     //proceed only if date time
     String paramNull = @"public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> edm{0} 
                        {{
                            get
                            {{
                                return {0}.HasValue ? new DateTimeOffset({0}.Value, TimeSpan.FromHours(0)) : (DateTimeOffset?)null;
                            }}
                        }}"; 

    String paramNotNull = @"public System.DateTimeOffset edm{0} 
                        {{
                            get
                            {{
                                return new DateTimeOffset({0}, TimeSpan.FromHours(0));
                            }}
                        }}"; 

        String s= String.Empty;
        if(edmProperty.Nullable){
        s = string.Format(paramNull, edmProperty.Name);     
        }else
        {
        s = string.Format(paramNotNull, edmProperty.Name);      
        }
        return s;

    }
```