# Telerik OpenAccess - Mapping Varchar to Int

Tags: telerik, odata, telerik-open-access

I'm trying to run an integer comparison (for instance greater than or less than) using OData on a value that is set to be a type of varchar in the database. Crossing out the solution of changing the database field to be a type of int, as it's not preferred in my specific case, is there a way to tell Telerik OpenAccess to convert the field to a type of integer when executing either the query or the mappings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is similar with this one: [Handling Dates with OData v4, EF6 and Web API v2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829422/handling-dates-with-odata-v4-ef6-and-web-api-v2-2/25076353#25076353)

Add one more proerpty:

```
public partial class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}

public partial class Title
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int IntProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return StringProperty==null?0;Int32.Parse(StringProperty);;
        }
        set
        {
            StringProperty = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Update the model:

```
public static IEdmModel GetModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    EntityTypeConfiguration<Title> titleType= builder.EntityType<Title>();
    titleType.Ignore(t => t.StringProperty);
    titleType.Property(t => t.IntProperty ).Name = "MyProperty";

    builder.EntitySet<Title>("Titles");

    builder.Namespace = typeof(Title).Namespace;

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```