# Web Api OData datetime issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Adding new entity to database via web api OData service keeps giving me the following error.
"Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.DateTime'. See the inner exception for more details." I googled a bit and found out that it's related to OData not supporting DateTime type. I am using EF with database first approach and some of the entities have properties which are of DateTime Type.

Any suggestion for the issue?

Thanks.
Nyi

Comment: You can refer to:
[How to get Web API OData v4 to use DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189557/how-to-get-web-api-odata-v4-to-use-datetime/25227159#25227159)

Comment: Thanks Sam Xu. It Wroks.