# Why does oData V4 not order on datetime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created a oData V4 endpoint with Web API 2.2 and Entity Framework. The model that is expose looks like the following model:

```
public class Items { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to the URL: /odata/Items it works like a charm. But when I go to the URL: /odata/Items?$orderby=CreatedOn I get the following error:

> 'The specified type member 'Kind' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.'

Comment: I have seen that post, but I got no trouble with showing the datetime. The end point gives back the correct datetime. But only when i try to order by the datetime i get this error. Did i miss a solution for this problem in that post?

Comment: Kind is a property on `System.DateTime` which describes whether it is Local or UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData v4 doesn't suport DateTime type. You should use DateTimeOffset instead. That's because of problems that can happen if you don't specify the time zone. In fact there is an open discussion if it shuld be supported or not.

Please, see this references:

- [SO Q&A: How to get Web API OData v4 to use DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189557/how-to-get-web-api-odata-v4-to-use-datetime)
- [OData V4 service should support DateTime #136](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/136)
- [OData V4 service should not support DateTime](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1753)

If you check those issues, you'll find that support for DateTime has been added to version 5.6.0 beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [Issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/293), and it's been fixed in [5.6.0 beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.6.0-beta1), please try it, if the issue still exist, please file an issue for us :).