# Cannot query (filter/select) for EF computed DateTimeOffset property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, odata

I have a WebAPI2 V4 OData controller which exposes my EF data models. One of the models has a `DateTime` property on it, which [isn't supported by OData V4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30025678/6427190).

I have added a custom computed `DateTimeOffset` property on my EF model with a getter and empty setter which just converts the datetime. I have also added an exclusion in my code first model builder to ignore this new property too. I got this suggestion from [this Microsoft discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e76c36b3-c8cb-4de8-ae4c-d214406e49b6/ef-41-dataservice-does-not-expose-properties-with-notmapped-attribute?forum=adodotnetdataservices).

```
public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirthOffset
{
    get
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(this.DateOfBirth);
    }
    set { }
}
```

In the DbCOntext OnModelCreating...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PortalUser>().Ignore(pu => pu.DateOfBirthOffset);
```

This does succesfully return the new property when I query the API like:

`baseuri:port/odata/Users`

But when I try to filter or select like:

`baseuri:port/odata/Users?$filter=DateOfBirthOffset lt 2010-01-25T02:13:40.1374695Z`

I get the following error:

**The specified type member 'DateOfBirthOffset' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**

Has anybody tried to do this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are ignoring the property in `modelBuilder`. Makes sense you can't query against it.

Comment: If I remove that ignore, I get the following error:
**Invalid column name 'DateOfBirthOffset**
which is why I ignored it in the first place. I just want it to be available to clients calling the API.

Comment: instead of ignoring it, try applying the `[NotMapped]` attribute to it.

Comment: That doesn't work either. That prevents the property from being selected. See NotMapped Attribute Convention on [this page](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/02-04-convention-model-builder/).

Comment: I'm talking about applying `[NotMapped]` to your EF entity, so that it won't be mapped to a column in your DB. I've done that in my OData projects, and I can query against such a property in my ViewModel (I'm not exposing my entities in my endpoints).

Comment: My EF model is my OData model so that won't work. This is an internal application, hence why we're just exposing all DB properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158627/discussion-between-dido-and-tophat-gordon).