# Calculated Properties in Odata v4 and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

Im working on a .Net Web Api 2.2 project and I'm using Odata v4 and Entity Framework code first.
I need to have a calculated  property in a Model which is not to be saved in Database.

I have tried `[notmapped]` attribute. But it hides the property in Odata $medadata.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add this property into model.

You can refer to the sample codes in: [How to get Web API OData v4 to use DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189557/how-to-get-web-api-odata-v4-to-use-datetime/25227159#25227159)

Hope it can help.