# After OData upgrade (5.9 to 7.4) DateTime properties can't be queried

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a working application in ASP.NET Web API 2 (not Core).  The app includes several `datetime` columns in the database (`DateTime` in C#).  Until now I've been using OData 5.9 in the app and I've been able to use filter those columns in `$filter` with ISO 8601 date strings.  I used the suggestion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452112/794234) to add `config.SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);` to my config and this worked great.

Fast forward to today.  I just upgraded the project to OData 7.4.  Everything went smoothly except for the `DateTime` properties.  I can no longer use those properties in my `$filter` without getting this error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is there some new configuration change I need to make to continue working with `DateTime` properties in OData 7.4?

Comment: Are the dates null?  It may be that OData fixed a bug where null dates were allowed and now not allowed.

Comment: @jdweng I've tried it with `DateTime?` and `DateTime` properties.  `DateTime?` gives the error in the question, `DateTime` gives a cast error.  Why would a nullable date not be allowed?

Comment: DataTime is c# cannot be null but in DataBase is can be null.  The question mark in c# for DateTime is not valid.  Ask Microsoft why a date cannot be null.  The best you can get is the default 1/1/1.