# Domain models aren't compatible with OData WebApi2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a number of models which were reverse engineered (code first) from the database. I would like to expose an OData service which a native mobile app and a web site will consume. However these models have a number of Nullable objects which are not compatible with OData. Is there a smart way to get this to work? Or will I have to create ViewModels which are compatible with OData for every one of my models?

For example

```
public class Product
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public Nullable<DateTime> DateUpdated {get;set;} //not compatible with OData must be DateTimeOffset
     .....
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "However these models have a number of Nullable objects which are not compatible with OData" What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its particularly `nullable` that's the issue, but rather `nullable<datetime>`.

See this related question: [Does OData v4 not support Nullable<DateTime>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635851/does-odata-v4-not-support-nullabledatetime).

If you are only after an implementation of the oData uri query syntax I would thoroughly recommend Linq to Querystring. We're using it on a large web api project to great success.

Here's the link: http://linqtoquerystring.net

Comment: To add - Linq to Querystring supports DateTime