# Odata Change to use System.DateTimeOffset or ignore this type by calling Ignore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have an odata error in:

```
  config.MapODataServiceRoute( "ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
```

> Error: The type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   of property 'NextBillingDate' in the 'Order' type is not a supported
>   type. Change to use 'System.DateTimeOffset' or ignore this type by
>   calling Ignore() on
>   'System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder'. Parameter name:
>   navigationProperty

I've tried everything... from:

```
public class ZOrder
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "NexBillingDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [ScriptIgnoreAttribute]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime? NextBillingDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DateTimeOffset? NexBillingDateOffSet
    {
        get { return NextBillingDate; }
        set { NextBillingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value); }
    }
}
```

[IgnoreDataMember], [ScriptIgnoreAttribute], nothing works... I've also tried:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        EntitySetConfiguration<Client> client = builder.EntitySet<Client>("Client_V1");
        EntitySetConfiguration<Coupon> cupon = builder.EntitySet<Coupon>("Coupon_V1");
        EntitySetConfiguration<Order> order =  builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders_V1");

        client.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.CreatedOn);
        client.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.ModifyOn);
        client.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.LastLogin);

        cupon.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.Start);
        cupon.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.End);

        order.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.NextBillingDate);
        order.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.CreatedOn);
        order.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.ModifyOn);


        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

    }
```

is .net ignoring order.EntityTyper() ??

Comment: Worse, I get this error although my field is not nullable. It seems that DateTime is not supported altogether. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23642791/95970